# How can I select years and quarters between 2 different years and 2 different quarters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
year    | quarter
2018    | 1
2018    | 2
2018    | 3
2018    | 4
2019    | 1
2019    | 2
2019    | 3
2019    | 4
```

I need to select all data from this table that would be between year 2018 quarter 2 and year 2019 quarter 3

I figured out select only for starting date:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    [usa].[dbo].[tmpDate]
WHERE   year != 2018
OR      quarter >= 2
```

which returns me:

```
year    | quarter
2018    | 2
2018    | 3
2018    | 4
2019    | 1
2019    | 2
2019    | 3
2019    | 4
```

What should be select to get:

```
year    | quarter
2018    | 2
2018    | 3
2018    | 4
2019    | 1
2019    | 2
2019    | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to make a small calculation with `year` and `quarter` values:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [year] int,
   [quarter] int
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([year], [quarter])
VALUES   
   (2018, 1),
   (2018, 2),
   (2018, 3), 
   (2018, 4), 
   (2019, 1), 
   (2019, 2), 
   (2019, 3), 
   (2019, 4)

-- Statement
SELECT *
FROM #Data
WHERE ([year] * 10 + [quarter]) BETWEEN 20182 AND 20193
ORDER BY [year], [quarter]
```

Output:

```
----------------
year    quarter
----------------
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2019    1
2019    2
2019    3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following query to get your expected result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [usa].[dbo].[tmpDate] 
WHERE (year = 2018 AND quarter >= 2) OR
      (year = 2019 AND quarter <= 3);
```

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TempData TABLE ([year] INT, [quarter] INT);

INSERT INTO @TempData ([year], [quarter]) VALUES
(2018, 1),
(2018, 2),
(2018, 3),
(2018, 4),
(2019, 1),
(2019, 2),
(2019, 3),
(2019, 4);

SELECT * 
FROM @TempData
WHERE ([year] = 2018 AND [quarter] >= 2) OR
      ([year] = 2019 AND [quarter] <= 3);
```

Output:

```
year    quarter
---------------
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2019    1
2019    2
2019    3
```

Comment: Will it work if end date changes to year 2018 and quarter 4?

Comment: Yes, we have OR condition with `([year] = 2019 AND [quarter] <= 3);`, so it won't return the 2019 records

Comment: _end date changes to year 2018 and quarter 4_ is this your [expectation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d873888bc64c07896ab09217cfd175ef) ?

Comment: Yes @Arulkumar, how will that select change if I will have start or end date change?

Answer (score 0):

Braces play an important role in WHERE clause. Try the following and let me know if it works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE (year = 2018 AND quarter >= 2) 
      OR (year = 2019 AND quarter <= 3)
```